# Entropy in classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am just few doubts in entropy. The entropy formula is given as
-summation(p(i|j) log2 p(i|j) 
This is the formula for target attribute which has only 2 values. What if the target has more than 2 class values (say high,medium and low) ? How will the formula gets affected ?
Will it be,
-summation(p(i|j) log3 p(i|j)) ?

Another question:
How to calculate the accuracy of random baseline classifier without any bias ?
Say my question says:

```
 1)class1=50% and class2=50%
 2)class1=40% and class2=60%
 3)class1=10%,class2=20% and class3=70%
```

Could you please help me in these two questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the usual choice for the logarithm remains base 2, "bits".

But in fact, the base of the log is just a constant, that in most cases cancels out or is a global scaling constant that does not matter.

Comment: thank you . Could you please also tell the answer for baseline accuracy ?

Comment: That part cannot be answered, it's incomplete.

Comment: This is actually a question asked in interview for me. I couldn't figure out the answer since they gave as unbiased.

Comment: In an interview, you can ask for clarification. I see a way to get an easy answer, probably what they were looking for. But you'd need to interactively check what they mean with "without any bias". That may even be part of the test!